# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key:string]:any;}

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am getting the following error on typescript file when I try to attach a click event handler as shown below,

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{
>   [key:string]:any;}

[image]

I have jQuery 2.1.4 and jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped 3.0.4 configured in my ASP.NET Web Application.

Edit:

My typescript file is able to pickup the definition file as shown below,

[image]

in my JQuery.d.ts,I see the following overloads,

```
on(events: string, handler: (eventObject: JQueryEventObject, ...args: any[]) => any): JQuery;
on(events: string, data : any, handler: (eventObject: JQueryEventObject, ...args: any[]) => any): JQuery;
on(events: string, selector: string, handler: (eventObject: JQueryEventObject, ...eventData: any[]) => any): JQuery;
on(events: string, selector: string, data: any, handler: (eventObject: JQueryEventObject, ...eventData: any[]) => any): JQuery;
on(events: { [key: string]: any; }, selector?: string, data?: any): JQuery;
on(events: { [key: string]: any; }, data?: any): JQuery;
```

What am I missing? Any hint / suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ran into this a while back, and if I'm not mistaken, this is due to the ordering of the overloads in the `on` definition in jquery.d.ts. Basically, because the definition includes the `[key:string]:any` overload before the `events: string` overload, the TypeScript parser fails to find it. I believe the latest version of the definition file on DefinitelyTyped (3.1.1) has corrected that.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, thank you. Let me try with the latest version.

Comment: I tried with the latest DefinitelyTyped (3.1.1) and did not work for me. I still see the same error.

Comment: What IDE are you using? It might be the IDE isn't picking up the change. For instance, Visual Studio ships with its own version of jQuery's definition.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Comment: Hmm... Do you have a `/// <reference` comment at the top of your script pointing to the jquery.d.ts file? I thought VS2015 automagically picked these things up, but it's been awhile since I used it for TypeScript.

Comment: No I did add the reference as my typescript file is able to pickup the definition file. Please see the edit section. As you can see in my code, the off('click') is working but, having problem with .on("click",

Comment: Wow, that's great. It shows the overload you're using, but still marks it as an error. Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Good luck!

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your guidance @MikeMcCaughan.

Comment: I bet the signature of your `changeEventHandler` does **not** specify the type `JQueryEventObject` for the first argument, and therefore the first overload is not applied. (That's what happened in my case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a minor issue in jquery.d.ts file. Instead of 'on', the jquery.d.ts file has 'one' (see the image below). Changing that fixed the issue.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is correct - there is a jquery function ```one``` as well as ```on``` and that's what those lines are declaring

Comment: There is a correct answer: [stackoverflow.com/questions/46862920](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862920/cant-use-foo-onclick-bar-with-jquery-and-typescript)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. None of the suggested solutions in the answers and comments did solve it for me.

Turned out that the signature of my eventHandler did **not** specify the type `JQueryEventObject` for the first argument, and therefore the first overload was not applied.

[image]
versus

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped 3.0.

Please stop using nuget for TypeScript type definitions.

## Best solution:

Just download and include this file in your project : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

## More

- Check that you are on TypeScript latest

Comment: for some reason, this url seems to be not working in my work environment. I am getting "This site can’t provide a secure connection. github.com sent an invalid response." Is there any other way to download the jquery.d.ts?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jquery.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts#L2348) the following typings are available for the `on` function:

```
1. on(events: string, selector: string, handler: (eventObject: JQueryEventObject, ...eventData: any[]) => any): JQuery;
2. on(events: string, selector: string, data: any, handler: (eventObject: JQueryEventObject, ...eventData: any[]) => any): JQuery;
3. on(events: { [key: string]: any; }, selector?: string, data?: any): JQuery;
4. on(events: { [key: string]: any; }, data?: any): JQuery;
```

Now since you are implementing the function the following way

```
$(this.elementId).on("click", changeEventHandler)
```

Either the 3rd or the 4th typing of `on` will get applied, which require the first element to be of type `{ [key: string]: any; }`. What you need to do is provide a selector to which the click function needs to be applied. So here are your options:

```
$(this.elementId).click(changeEventHandler)
OR
$(document).on("click", this.elementId, changeEventHandler)
```

The thing that you were missing is that when using the `on` function along with the event type and the event handler you also need to specify the DOMElement on which the listener is to be attached

Comment: Thank you. $(this.elementId).click(changeEventHandler) seems to be working for me. But, in the jquery.d.ts file, 6 typings are available for the on function. Please see the edit section in question.

Comment: Yes but the way you were calling it i.e. `$(this.elementId).on("click", changeEventHandler)` there were only two arguments in the `on` function which is why typescript woud apply the type `on(events: { [key: string]: any; }, data?: any): JQuery;` to your function and hence the reason for your type mismatch

Comment: in my case, the first 'on' has two argument too... on(events: string, handler: (eventObject: JQueryEventObject, ...args: any[]) => any): JQuery; Why is it not picking up?

Answer (score 1):

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862920](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862920/argument-of-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-keystring) already has the answer:

```
$("#some-element").on("click", function(event:JQuery.Event) {
     // code
}
```