# Can't use $('.foo').on('click', '.bar', with jQuery and TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript, events

I am using TypeScript and jQuery in a project and I need to use jQuery's `on` to listen to an event:

```
const $previewListWrp: jQuery<HTMLElement> = $('.js-preview-list-wrp').first();

$previewListWrp.on('click', '.btn-action.remove', (evt: Event): void => {
  let $box: JQuery<HTMLElement> = $(evt.target).closest('.js-preview-wrp');
  console.log($box.data());
});
```

However, I get the error

> Argument of type '"click"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PlainObject void> | EventHandlerBase

Just started a new project and installed the latest versions of TypeScript, jQuery and @types/jQuery.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try changing evt: EventTarget to evt: JQuery.Event

Comment: Thanks, it works. Still, care to elaborate a little more?

Comment: `Event` represents the DOM Event object. However, jQuery passes an object of type `JQuery.Event`. These types are not compatible. Declaring `evt` as `Event` results in a function type that won't match any overload and produces the error. In this case, I recommend not declaring the type of `evt` explicitly and allow it to be inferred from the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the alternative signature of the `on` method, in which the first argument is indeed an object, and do:

```
$previewListWrp.on({
    'click': (evt: EventTarget): void => {
        console.log(evt);
    }
}, '.btn-action.remove');
```

Comment: Now I get this error: `[ts]
Argument of type '{ 'click': (evt: EventTarget) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PlainObject<false | EventHandler<HTMLElement, string> | EventHandlerBase<any, Event<HTMLElement, ...'` and some other stuff I can't post because it wouldn't feet in comment.
`

Comment: To whoever edited my original question, thanks. However, the type is indeed `JQuery` (with a capital "j") for `JQuery<HTMLElement>`. If not, then I understand things even less than I would like to admit.

Comment: @Shiladitya, please take note of what Fernando just said. Fernando, you can restore that by editing your question again.

Comment: It looks like writing the callback handler function **without** defining the type for `evt` **works**, that is `(evt) => { ... }` instead of `(evt: EventTarget) => { ... }`. The type definition clearly states that `evt` is of a type that extends `EventTarget`.